# use try() inside foreach() in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am try to use try() inside foreach in php for facebook application my app get user permissions than post on his 3 friends wall but the problem is that if one of user friends is non-postable than my app stop with error below is my code and error please take a look

```
        foreach ($friends_list_array["data"] as $value) {
                                                        try
                                                                {
         // compile the post for for user
        $WallPost = array(
        'access_token' => $atoken,
            'message' => $value["name"] . ' .. message here  ',
            'link' => 'link_here');  


        // post to user wall
        $response = $facebook->api('/' . $value["id"] . '/feed','POST',$WallPost);


        echo ' posted on ' . $value["name"];

                                                                    }
    }
```

all works fine(except non-postable wall problem) without `try()`  its shows error below is error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting T_CATCH in**

Can any one please solve this thank you

Comment: @Jashwant i dont need catch i just want to ignore the friend if his/her wall is non-postable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php/)

> Each try must have at least one corresponding catch block

And thats the answer to your problem ( the error itself says about it, `expecting T_CATCH`)

Comment: thanks after reading your comment that i have to search about catch and add catch just for testing purpose and got success now my problem is already solved thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome Abdullah. Always refer [php.net](http://wwww.php.net/). I am not a very good php developer, but it makes me feel like one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need catch, just don't fill it with any logic, working example:

```
foreach ($friends_list_array["data"] as $value) {
 try{
  // do stuff...
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
  // do nothing
 }
}
```